# How can I truncate an HTML table

Tags: layout, html

How do I truncate a table if it is wider than its container?

For example, say I have a div with width = 300px;

Inside the div: one table with 2 td, each with width = 200px;

Obviously, 200 + 200 > 300. 
However, what HTML does is make each td 150px wide.

Is there a way to respect the td width (200) and truncate the last td so that only its left half is visible?

I have tried overflow:hidden on the div but the table is still 300px wide

Answer (score 0):

Set the wrapping div to overflow hidden:

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qmby4/

Comment: Joseph, it's almost what I need. However, I don't want to specify the width of the table. Is it possible to have the width of the table come from its columns, not the containing div?

Answer (score 0):

Please try using [max-width](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/width.html) property

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS overflow:auto tag on your div.
Check out more here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: Mike 







it's almost what I need. However, I don't want to specify the width of the table. Is it possible to have the width of the table come from its columns, not the containing div?

Comment: If your table has no defined width, it should respect your td's widths.  However, it's pretty easy to goof up CSS global settings around tables, trs, and tds.  Can you post your HTML and CSS so I can see what you're trying to get?  I think it's about there.